# Invoking MsDeploy.exe manually in a Azure Devops

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy, msdeploy

**Background**

As part of our deployment pipeline we are creating our deployment artifact, by running several .xdt transforms on our build artifact as well as adding several additional files.

As the last step before publishing, we would like to invoke msdeploy.exe to build a "custom" webdeploy package from a folder containing the wwwroot-content - (msdeploy command for creating custom package found in this question [Web Deploy - How to create a package with selected items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36908277/web-deploy-how-to-create-a-package-with-selected-items))

We are using hosted agents (win 2017).

We wish to deploy to an Azure AppService.

**Question**

Is there a task in Azure DevOps, that allows you to invoke MsDeploy.exe manually, such that we can create a custom webdeploy package, before we deploy?

Comment: Did you notice the `command line` task?

Comment: Yes I was considering that but I was unsure how to determine the msdeploy path on the hosted agents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a task in Azure DevOps, that allows you to invoke MsDeploy.exe manually, such that we can create a custom webdeploy package, before we deploy?

I am afraid there is no such task to invoke MsDeploy.exe manually. We need invoke it by command line task, just like Daniel comment.

As we know, the default installation will place `msdeploy.exe` in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
```

To verify the msdeploy path on the hosted agents, I use a [copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) with content `**\msdeploy.exe`:

[image]

Then use the Publish build artifacts to output the `msdeploy.exe`, I could get the result on the hosted agent **vs2017-win2016** and **windows-2019**:

[image]

So, the  the msdeploy path on the hosted agents **vs2017-win2016** and **windows-2019** is `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe`. We could use command line task to invoke it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the exact CommandLine task that worked for me (without parameters though):

[image]

Comment: I used this approach, you need to have the Web Deploy installed on IIS, it was not installed by default: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy